# Xamarin run error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The "Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GetApiLevelFromFramework" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  xamarin_installed_trial
```

I get this error when I want to run an android program using xamarin.

[Android sdk is properly installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbpjh.png)[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqvdx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the target platforms are installed correctly. In **Visual Studio ->Android SDK MANAGER -> Platforms**

You can check
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=vswin)

Comment: Can you try change your projects target platform ?